# Документация по библеотеке XMPP для PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите где найти документацию по библеотеке XMPP для PHP? Весь интернет облазил, ничего путного не нашёл. Единственное что нашёл - как отправлять сообщения на клиент, но хотелось бы найти полную документацию данной библеотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не то ли, что вам нужно лежит здесь:

[Ссылка раз](http://jawiki.ru/XMPPHP)
[Ссылка два](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/)

Comment: да я это уже сто раз видел. Где вы там нашли документацию по данной библеотеке?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "документацией"? Есть спецификация протокола, а по данным ссылкам описано как пользоваться этой библиотекой.